# I'm trying to make a button to count characters in a text field

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to use the `JButton count` to count the number of characters entered into the `JTextField t`. I'm new to Java and GUIs but here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI1 extends Frame implements ActionListener{

    TextField t; 
    Button count;
    int a;
    Choice choice;

    public GUI1(){

        this.t = new TextField("", 30);

        this.count = new Button("count");
        this.count.addActionListener(this);

        JTextField x = new JTextField();
        x.setEditable(false);

        this.setTitle("Character count");
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        this.add(x);
        this.add(t);
        this.add(count);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()== this.count) 


       t.setText(choice.getSelectedItem()+ " " +a);
    }
```

I'm also trying to enter the value in another uneditable `JTextField x`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you not to use `AWT` elements, since it brings tons of problems and it has little to no support, instead you can try using `Swing` components which are a replacement/fix for AWT. You can read more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442672/is-swing-still-in-use-today). You might also want to read [AWT vs Swing (Pros and Cons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994304/is-java-swing-still-in-use).

Now going into your problem:

You should avoid extending from `JFrame`, I might recommend you to create a new `JFrame` object instead. [Here's the reason to why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components). That being said, you can also remove all your `this.t` and other calls with `this`.

I'm glad you're using a Layout Manager!

And now to count the number of characters on your `JTextField` and set text to your other `JTextField` you should use this code:

```
count.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int count = t.getText().length();
        System.out.println(count);
        x.setText(t.getText());
    }
});
```

Also I fixed your code, I changed AWT elements to Swing ones and added number of cols to your second `JTextField` so it would appear.

So, here's a running example that I made from your code (And removed `Choice choice` line since you didn't posted that code):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI1 {

    JTextField t; 
    JButton count;
    int a;
    JFrame frame;

    public GUI1(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        t = new JTextField("", 15);
        count = new JButton("count");
        JTextField x = new JTextField("", 15);
        x.setEditable(false);

        count.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int count = t.getText().length();
                System.out.println(count);
                x.setText(t.getText());
            }
        });

        frame.setTitle("Character count");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.add(x);
        frame.add(t);
        frame.add(count);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new GUI1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your code

```
count.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    a = t.getText().length();
 }
});
```

OR

You can use lambda expression like this

```
count.addActionListener(e -> a = t.getText().length());
```

For More
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a listener

```
TextField t = new TextField();

Button b = new Button("Count");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int count = t.getText().length();
     }
});
```

You can read more about here

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/awt/awt_button.htm

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a button you should

```
String str = t.getText(); // get string from jtextfield
```

To save the text from the texfield. Then you can use something like:

```
a = str..length(); // get length of string
x.setText(str + " " + a); //set it to the field
```

To set it to the  JTextField.