# Java won't render graphics onto frame

Tags: java, eclipse

Using the below code, graphics won't render on the screen no matter what I try.

```
package local.ryan.grid;

import java.awt.BufferCapabilities;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game implements Runnable {

    public boolean isRunning = false;

    private long lastTime;
    private double fps;
    public int gamestage = 0;
    public Frame frame = new Frame(2, 300, 300, "Ok");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread game = new Thread(new Game());
        game.start();

    }

    public void run() {

        start();

        while(isRunning) {

            lastTime = System.nanoTime();

            try {

                // Limit Each Frame, to 60 fps.
                // Prevents performance issues with multiple objects.

            Thread.sleep(1000 / 60); // 1000 miliseconds (1 second) / 60 frames-per-second ~ 17 ms.



            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            render();

            fps = 1000000000D / (System.nanoTime() - lastTime); //one second(nano) divided by amount of time it takes for one frame to finish
            lastTime = System.nanoTime();

            // Change to integer, to remove decimals.
            System.out.println("FPS: " + (int) fps + ".");

        }

    }

    public void render(){

           BufferStrategy bs = frame.getBufferStrategy();

           if (bs== null){

           frame.createBufferStrategy(3);
           return;

           }

           Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bs.getDrawGraphics();

            //Draws a background and a line for testing
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(50, 50, 200, 50);

            //Displays the graphics to the frame
            frame.update(g);
            g.dispose();
            bs.show();

        }

    public void start() {

        if(isRunning)
            return;

        isRunning = true;


    }

    public void stop() {

        if(!isRunning)
            return;

        isRunning = false;


    }

}
```

I also have a class called `Frame` to create a frame:

```
package local.ryan.grid;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame(int scale, int x, int y, String title) {

        setTitle(title);
        setSize(x, y);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {

        return this;

    }

}
```

Comment: If some of the code is written incorrectly, or inefficient, please don't bother. Please refrain and remain answering the actual problem. Thank you!

Comment: Changed 'Frame' at the top, to JFrame.

Comment: You never call `frame.setVisible(true);`

Comment: lmao thats not the issue. I did, in the other method. @SnakeDoc

Comment: As an aside, you may be interested in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442672/is-swing-still-in-use-today/24442709#24442709

Comment: Can you post your code with `frame.setVisible(true);`, because it's not in the sample you provided above.

Comment: If you're using a JFrame, you should be doing your drawing in its `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: Ok, I added my code. And, @Frecklefoot what would that look like?

Comment: Freckle, I did it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
package local.ryan.grid;

import java.awt.BufferCapabilities;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game implements Runnable {

    public boolean isRunning = false;

    private long lastTime;
    private double fps;
    public int gamestage = 0;
    public JFrame frame = new Frame(2, 300, 300, "Ok");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread game = new Thread(new Game());
        game.start();

    }

    public void run() {

        start();

        while(isRunning) {

            lastTime = System.nanoTime();

            try {

                // Limit Each Frame, to 60 fps.
                // Prevents performance issues with multiple objects.

            Thread.sleep(1000 / 60); // 1000 miliseconds (1 second) / 60 frames-per-second ~ 17 ms.



            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            render(frame.getGraphics());

            fps = 1000000000D / (System.nanoTime() - lastTime); //one second(nano) divided by amount of time it takes for one frame to finish
            lastTime = System.nanoTime();

            // Change to integer, to remove decimals.
            System.out.println("FPS: " + (int) fps + ".");

        }

    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {    

        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(10,10,100f,100f);
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
        ga.draw(circle);

    }  

    public void start() {

        if(isRunning)
            return;

        isRunning = true;


    }

    public void stop() {

        if(!isRunning)
            return;

        isRunning = false;


    }

}
```

Probably not the best way to do it, but it worked!